# Display NavigationController from AppDelegate when Push Notification Arrives

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

[image]

This is the current Setup I've for the Display of the Chat Conversation.

1): Push Notification Arrives

2): didRecieveRemoteNotification: Gets the Payload and Performs a **NSNotification** Post to the Root View Controller ( Initial View ) Which is a **UITabBarController**

3): UITabBarController Receives the NSNotification. Observer and executes a function that performs (  [self setSelectedIndex:2]; ) And sends the same payload using **NSNotification**

4): NavigationController Recieves the NSNotification Payload using a Observer Executes the function and performs the Push Segue to the Chat conversation Viewcontroller Embedded on the UINavigationController

This steps works for me except is a long way to pass the data many times until arrives to the final destination, not to mention that this  causes problems when making many pushes causing corrupted **NavigationController**.

What I would like to achieve is from the AppDelegate show Chat Conversation ViewController with it's **NavigationController** and don't cause the same corrupt ***navigationController*** when making the same Display over and Over again. And at the same time pass it the PayLoad from the Push Notification.

Here is my AppDelegate didRecieveRemoteNotification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"viewController"]  isEqual: @"chat_controller"]){

        if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
        {
            NSDictionary *userDictionary = @{@"nick_from" : [userInfo objectForKey:@"nick_from"],@"nick_to" : [userInfo objectForKey:@"nick_to"]};

            [self pushChatNotification:userDictionary];
        }
        else {

            NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ sent you a message want to reply?",[userInfo objectForKey:@"nick_from"]];

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New message"
                                                                message:message
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Reply"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
            [alertView show];

        }

    }


}


-(void)pushChatNotification:(NSDictionary *)userDictionary {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"conversationParameters"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userDictionary];

}
```